# Javascript: Convert string to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i convert this string into object so that i can access it's property like `obj.Name` ?

```js
{
    Name = Mahbubr Rahman, 
    Gender = Male, 
    Birthday = 1 / 5 / 1992 6: 00: 00 AM, 
    Email = mahbubur.rahman@ rms.com, 
    EmployeeType = Manager
}
```

I have tried with `JSON.parse()` and `eval` but getting nothing. Any help ?

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify('{ Name = Mahbubr Rahman,Gender = Male, Birthday = 1/5/1992 6:00:00 AM, Email = mahbubur.rahman@rms.com, EmployeeType = Manager }'.replace(/=/g, ':'))
);
```

Comment: Can you not change the format the strings are stored in to be valid JSON? Then you could just use `JSON.parse()`. Having to hack around a string in to the right format seems to be fixing the wrong part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one as well

```js
var str = "{ Name = Mahbubr Rahman,Gender = Male, Birthday = 1/5/1992 6:00:00 AM, Email = mahbubur.rahman@rms.com, EmployeeType = Manager }"

var obj = JSON.parse(str.split(/\s*=\s*/).join("\":\"").split(/\s*,\s*/).join("\",\"").split(/{\s*/).join("{\"").split(/\s*}/).join("\"}"));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following. Wrap all property name and value with double quotes (") and replace `=` with `:`.

```
var st = '{ Name = Mahbubr Rahman, Gender = Male, Birthday = 1/5/1992 6:00:00 AM, Email = mahbubur.rahman@rms.com, EmployeeType = Manager }';
st = st.replace(/=/g, '":"');
st = st.replace(/{/g, '{"');
st = st.replace(/}/g, '"}');
st = st.replace(/,/g, '","');

var obj = JSON.parse(st);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var str = '{ Name = Mahbubr Rahman,Gender = Male, Birthday = 1/5/1992 6:00:00 AM, Email = mahbubur.rahman@rms.com, EmployeeType = Manager }';

str = str.replace(/=/g, '\":\"');
str = str.replace(/,/g, "\", \"");
str = str.replace(/{/g, "{\"");
str = str.replace(/}/g, "\"}");

console.log(str);

var obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj);
```